# Can't log in to sandbox test accounts on PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

I have logged into the paypal developer site using my (new and verified) Paypal account, I next browsed to Dashboard>Sandbox>accounts, I created two accounts here: first is a buyer(personal) accont and second a bussines (merchant) account.

I than press "Click Here" and I am than forwarded to a page indicating:

"We're sorry. Relying party validation error: client_id or redirect_url provided in the request does not match any of the registered clients. Please check the request and try again."